# How can I tell which message format an Outlook MSG file was composed with?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I need to determine what message format (Plain-text, RTF, HTML, etc)  an email message is in.  I have the `.MSG` file from the sender's sent items folder.  Is there a way I can check this in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the email messages header. Depending on your email client this can be achieved a number of ways.

Steps in outlook to see the message header:

1. Open the message in a new window in Outlook.
2. Select View | Options... from the message's menu
3. All header lines appear under Internet Headers at the bottom of the dialog that comes up.

At the end of the header you'll see a line like this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8
```

If the `Content-Type` is `text/plain` it's text only and if it's `text/html` then it's HTML.

Comment: And Outlook E-Mails are sended like this: `Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"`

Comment: For those coming here with a newer Outlook than used back in 2011, Click *File* menu and then press the *Properties* button.  This will display the 'Properties' window that contains the 'Internet headers' section